# How to write a collation rule for elasticsearch icu_collation_keyword field, with alphabets having at most precedence?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, collation

Instead of using alternative locale option, I want to write a rules parameter to customise the sort behaviour with alphabets having atmost precedence.

for the text values, $1232, Abi, £7232, 87343, Karthik

I want the collation rule, to have the following sort order

- Abi
- Karthik
- $1232
- £7232
- 87343

So far i have tried with the following mapping

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {   
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "sort": {  
            "type": "icu_collation_keyword",
            "index": false,
            "language" : "en"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the above locale option (language) instead of rules option, sorts in the following order

- $1232
- £7232
- 87343
- Abi
- Karthik

Can someone please let me know how to write a collation rule, so that the alphabets have the precedence above all other

alphabets -> space -> punctuation -> symbol -> currency -> digits -> others

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update. Hi @all tried using the following collation rule in the mapping as it was working with java collator code snippet.

"< a,A < b,B < c,C < d,D < e,E < f,F < g,G < h,H < i,I < j,J < k,K < l,L < m,M < n,N < o,O < p,P < q,Q < r,R < s,S < t,T< u,U < v,V < w,W < x,X < y,Y < z,Z"

But using same in the elasticsearch mapping throwing a parse exception

::: expected a reset or setting or comment at index 0

Comment: Update. Hi @all . I found the reason why there was a parse exception, the one that was working fine for collation rules is the method of java.text package, but the one that elasticsearch is using is com.ibm package. can someone please tell me what is the ibm package equivalent of the above rule

Answer (score 0):

Hi @all The following collation rule setting working for the use case.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {   
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "sort": {  
            "type": "icu_collation_keyword",
            "index": false,
            "rules" :   "[reorder Latn digit space punct currency others]",
            "alternate" : "shifted"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
enter code here
```

Thank you!